# angularjs custom directive two way binding watch not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I created a custom directive and am using two way binding (=)

But I want to watch changes in controller when model is changed in directive.

alert should appear when user changes input but alert appears only one time at the beginning.

My javascript

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', [])

    .controller("myCtrl", function ($scope) {
    $scope.test = "myValue";
    $scope.$watch('myValue', function () {
        alert('hey, myVar has changed!');
    });
})

    .directive('myDirective', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        scope: {
            myModel: '=ngModel'
        },
        template: '<input ng-model="myModel"/>'
    }
});
```

and html

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="myCtrl">{{test}}
        <my-directive ng-model="test"></my-directive>
    </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/c7nbk8uq/

Answer (score 1):

You are watching the wrong variable?

```
$scope.$watch('test', function() {
       alert('hey, myVar has changed!');
   });
```

Answer (score 1):

You misspelled 'myValue' and 'test'.

```
 $scope.$watch('test', function() {
       alert('hey, myVar has changed!');
   });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pmydr7qp/